# Can std::initializer_list be constexpr(GCC and Clang disagree)?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, initializer-list

Godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/g/96oSd5) here for clang error,

source:

```
#include <initializer_list>
int main(){
    constexpr std::initializer_list<char> chars{'a','b','c'};
}
```

If somebody wonders VC++ gives some useless errors :)